# preventing a key press event after a collision event:

Tags: c#, picturebox, collision, keypress

I am trying to make a game and I want to make an item where the player picks it up and it doesn't allow them to jump anymore. So when the picture box of the player collides with the picture of the item I want an event to trigger where the player can't jump anymore but I don't know what to add to make the jump key not do anything when it is pressed after the collision event. Any advice?

Comment: Wouldn't be easier with a flag?

Comment: I'm not sure why you would want to use collision detection, at all. If the item is picked up, simply don't allow the player to jump (otherwise, the player won't be able to jump simply because they're in the same vicinity as the object). Maybe I need more coffee? What's your reasoning for not wanting it to be handled when the jump button is pressed? That seems like a logical place to put that functionality.

Comment: I am bit of a newcomer to coding so I'm using picture boxes until I learn more about items and the like and the problem is I don't know how to stop the player from jumping once the event has been triggered as I don't know what I have to put in the coding.

Comment: Can you show us some of your code?

Answer (score 0):

Without code, we cant help you very much...

One simple shot in the dark, something like rectangle intersection?

```
System.Drawing.Rectangle player = new Rectangle(width, height, x, y);
Rectangle item = new Rectangle(width, height, x, y);
if(player.Intersects(item))
{
  canJump = false;
}
```